# Multiple clients sending notifications using Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

We want to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send messages to mobile devices (same app on all the devices, one Firebase project) from multiple senders. We do not want to expose the server key to all the senders. How can we set up FCM in a way that the senders can be authenticated and have the right to send a push message?

In addition we would like the senders to be able to view their statistics regarding the messages they sent. But only that, we do not want the senders to have any other access to the project. Can this be done in Firebase?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a whitelisted FCM application, that you then provide to multiple, unrelated customers.

In that case you should create a separate Firebase project for each customer. While leads to having to do some setup work for each customer, it's the only way to reach your other goals within the constraints set for Firebase projects.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for your reply.
We hope to get thousands of customers so this would mean thousands of projects.
Is there a limit to the number of projects using the same App?

Comment: Not really, although there is a limit on the number of free projects you can have per account. I'd recommend having the users/tenants creating their own project, or you setting it up and transferring ownership to them.

Comment: Is it possible to white label these projects to our customers so they see our logo and connect via our url?

Comment: Not with the Firebase console. You would have to build your own app admin console for that.